# Clean off the [Dashboard] tag

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

[dashboard](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dashboard) looks pretty meta to me... It does not describe one single product, or even one company. Is there an expert on every dashboard available to answer all the questions?

I think we need to get rid of it

Comment: Dashboard refers to specific functionality.  Text editor doesn't describe a single product or company.  Same with Printing,  documentation, browser and partitioning to name a few.  What would you replace it with for questions that are about the function rather than a specific product?  I don't see the tag as being a problem.